# JavaScript(JQuery)がSyntaxエラーを招いているが理由を特定できない（Eclipse上）

Tags: javascript, jquery, eclipse

超がつくほどの初心者です。
画面上に配置された一つのチェックボックスの変化で動作させる処理が
他の項目（主にINPUT type=text）の変化でも、動作させる必要があることに気が付きました。

その処理をFunctionにして、チェックボックスの変化だけでなく、他の項目の変化でも呼び出すようにしようと考えています。

```
function　updRenew () {
        // MCFrame内予約情報を表示するためのヘッダを表示
        $(".updHeader").css("display", "table");

        //********************* メイン入力行を新たに手配しなおす***********************
        $("div.appLines table tr:not(.appLineDummy)").remove();
        $("#norsvmsg").remove();
        // 更新モードはメイン入力行を5行にしてしまう （既存予約行のクリックで適時増やす）
        for(var i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
            addRowBelow($dummyRow);
        }
        $(".appLines").height(7.85 + 'em');
        //*********************************************************************

        $("body").append('<div id="modal-overlay"></div>') ;
        $("#modal-overlay").append("<img id='loader' src='./img/ajax-loader.gif' alt='Now Loading...'>");
        $("#modal-overlay").fadeIn("slow");

        var d = mcrsvinq();
        d.done(function(){
            $(".updLines").fadeIn("slow");
            $("#loader").remove();
            $("#modal-overlay").fadeOut("slow", function(){
                $('#modal-overlay').remove();
            });
        });
        d.fail(function(){
            $("#modal-overlay").fadeOut("slow", function(){
                $('#modal-overlay').remove();
            });
            alert("【基幹システムから予約情報を参照できず...】");
            return false;
        });
    }
```

開発ツールはEclipseですが、当該のFunctionでSyntaxエラーを招いているかのような表示をしており
これをどうにか解決したいです。（下の画像のとおり赤く示されているので当方はSyntaxエラーと解釈）
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]
但し、PHPのサイトなのですが、実行すると無事に動作してしまいます。ブラウザの開発ツールでも問題のJSが普通に動作します。

Eclipse上、赤く表示され続けているのが　やはり気分が良くないので問題？！を解決したいです。

何が問題で、赤く表示されているのでしょうか？

Comment: ご丁寧な説明をありがとうございました。
確かに不用意な全角スペースが入っていました。
お手間をとらせて申し訳ございませんでした。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> (U+3000) is not a valid identifier start char

がヒントになります。

`function　updRenew`
に全角スペースが含まれています。

Comment: ご指摘の部分に確かに全角文字が入っていました。
くだらないことでお時間を頂戴して申し訳ございませんでした。
また迅速なご支援をありがとうございました。

Answer (score 3):

該当行に U+3000 全角スペースが含まれていることを Eclipse が警告しているのだと思われます。

ですが実は規格上は全角スペースを使っても構いません。ECMA-262 では以下の文字が空白として使えることになっています。

- U+0009 CHARACTER TABULATION
- U+000B LINE TABULATION
- U+000C FORM FEED
- U+0020 SPACE
- U+00A0 NO-BREAK SPACE
- U+FEFF ZERO WIDTH NO-BREAK SPACE
- Zsカテゴリの任意の文字

U+3000 は Zs カテゴリの文字なので、空白として使えます。

ただ、古いブラウザの対応や文字コード誤認した場合のトラブルを考えると、U+3000 などの非ASCII文字は使わない方が無難です。